# How do i add a click event on an icon in the taskbar?

Tags: c#, winforms

My Form1 is shown in the taskbar on the bottom.
I want that when i click on the icon it will do something. Not maximize the form but do something else.

I have a form1 click event:

```
private void Form1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(30000);
        }
```

But this will work only when i click on the form when the form is maximized.
I want it to work only when i click on the icon in the taskbar. Not tray icon on the right bottom corner but on the taskbar on the bottom.

EDIT**

I didn't find any click event for the icon of the form when it's in the taskbar what i did so far is using the form1 resi8ze event and did:

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
            {
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
                notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
                notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(30000);

            }
        }
```

I also did in the Form1 Load event:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

So the result now is that when i'm running the program the form icon is in the taskbar all the time the form never maximize resize or open . when i click on the icon in the taskbar the balloon tip is working good.

The problems now is:

1. Remove somehow the window of the form when you move the mouse over the icon.
2. to lock/disable/avoid the user from being clicking the icon many times. Once the user clicked the icon wait 5 minutes and enabled it again.

Comment: Looks like a job for some fun wih P/Invoke... good luck!

Comment: Need more details about the desired behavior, step by step

Comment: Alex. 1. The form will not shown on the screen and not on the tray icon only on the taskbar as icon. 2. When clicking on the icon in the taskbar it will do something not open/resize/maximize the form just will do something like activate a timer. 3. when moving the mouse pointer over the icon in the taskbar it will not show the form in a small window as it's doing now but will how a small text above it like a balloon. 4. When clicking on the icon and when it's doing something like activating a timer it will also disable the icon so the user won't be able to click on it again for 5 minutes.

Comment: Alex i just updated my question with what i did so far and what i need to do more.

Comment: Alex try the Paint program that come with the windows. When you install it you see it's icon on the taskbar in the bottom. When you move the mouse cursour over it you see small text say Paint. When you click on the icon it's running an event and running the program Paint.exe now try to run some empty just some c# application you will see it's icon on the taskbar. If you move the mouse cursour over it it will show small window of the form like a preview window.  and if you click on it it will open the form to the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get familiar with [WindowsAPICodePack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) and [Taskbar API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942846.aspx). I have never done exactly what you need, but those are pretty powerful APIs and might come handy.